# how to activate ios.windows xamarin on windows

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin.ios, xamarin

Installed `Xamarin.iOS` on Windows and I can see it in Visual Studio 2010, and the Mac Build host is there and running but It is not configured in the Visual Studio iOS extension. 
When I try to configure it, it says

> Please activate your Xamarin.iOS before you can configure your build
>   host.

But there is no option to activate the `Xamarin.iOS`, how to do that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appeared that you need to create a new project to force it to Activate as it says in here
http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/1527/force-activation-in-windows-xamarin-ios